# Cypress can't see rails server output from within the same docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, cypress

I'm attempting to get cypress working with rails in a single docker container. I'm using the Simplest possible Rails 6 + docker-compose project (at https://github.com/bdavidxyz/simplest-rails-docker), with cypress/included:3.8.1 (at https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/tree/master/included), based on the End-to-End Testing Web Apps: The Painless Way blog (at https://mtlynch.io/painless-web-app-testing/).

After building, I run docker-compose up and cypress tries to start. Then the rails server starts, cypress succeeds and tests run.

Cypress baseurl http://web-srv:3000/ gets 403
"landing" http://host.docker.internal:3000/ ECONNREFUSED 192.168.65.2:3000
google https://google.com works
localhost http://localhost:3000/hello/say_hello ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
---but I do see the rails welcome on a browser at localhost:3000.

Does anyone know a way to get Cypress to see the Rails output?

For clarity, I made a gitub repository with code and steps to reproduce: https://github.com/Sambalero/docker-cypress-rails (I'm on windows 10)

Thank you!